# Ember jQuery detach issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I am trying to do some DOM updates (detatching some element & append it somewhere else)

```
var comp = Ember.$(this.element).detach();
Ember.$("#some-sec").append(comp);
```

However for some reasons, the earlier event handling goes for a toss after doing this.
Am I doing something wrong ? Is this to be done in a different way for an Ember app ?

The code is called from inside the component as below;

```
didRender: function(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.updateCustomDOM, 20);
},
```

Comment: is `this` a component? What are the eventhandlers (Ember or jQuery?) bound to? I think we'd need to know more about the ember context.

Comment: Yes, this code is written within a custom Ember component..So yes, 'this' refers to the component

Comment: depending on the condition (when you wanna detach it) the Ember way would be to set a property in the _parent_ component. like `{{#if condition}}{{childComponent someProp=value}}{{/if}}`

Comment: ..but as I don´t see the circumstances it´s hard to answer. Also what are the eventhadlers bound to?

Comment: Added more details to the question...it is called from component's didRender handle.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to move component's element into another place, you
   should do it in `didInsertElement` hook. On re-render Ember will update it correctly.
2. `append` is enough to move element, you don't need `detach`:

   ```
   Ember.$("#some-sec").append(this.$());
   ```
3. When I do such trick, I attach events *after* moving element (not sure if it matters)
4. Remove element from DOM in `willDestroyElement` hook:

   ```
   this.$().remove();
   ```

`this.$()` contains component's element wrapped in jquery's `$()`